# In QGIS 3 Graphical Modeler can you add a check box to allow for different model path

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-modeler

In the Graphical Modeler in QGIS 3 is it possible to add a check box to the model GUI that if selected takes you down a different path of the tree so to speak.

**Example:**

Within a model I want to have two options for the geometric predicate in the select by location tool (intersect and within). Currently in the model interface you do not have an option to select multiple criteria. I would like the model to have a check box, which if selected will lead to another geometric predicate in the model.

Of course it would also be useful to apply this to many other scenarios too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I now know that this is going to be possible with a new addition to the QGIS modeler coming with version 3.14. Details of this can be found by [clicking here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/35808)

This new addition will introduce a new model only algorithm for creating conditional branches to your model. This is going to be a great addition so thanks to the sponsor and developer.

*'GIF credit goes to nyalldawson at North Road'*
[image]